# Is there a way to make pandas pd.crosstab default to include margins=True?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

The default behavior of pd.crosstab in pandas is as follows, which does not include margins:

```
`pandas.crosstab(index, columns, values=None, rownames=None, colnames=None, aggfunc=None, margins=False, margins_name='All', dropna=True, normalize=False)`
```

Is there a way to change the default behavior of pd.crosstab?

I know we can use partialmethod to change the default parameter values in python. e.g. to change pandas sort_values to ascending, we can do

```
from functools import partialmethod
pd.DataFrame.sort_values = partialmethod(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, ascending=False)
```

I tried doing this:
`pd.crosstab = partialmethod(pd.crosstab, margins=True)`
but received this error:
`TypeError: 'partialmethod' object is not callable`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

> `class functools.partialmethod(func, /, *args, **keywords)`
> Return a new partialmethod descriptor which behaves like partial *except that it is designed to be used as a method definition rather than being directly callable.*

That is why you are getting that error. Try [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) instead:

```
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array(["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar",
              "bar", "bar", "foo", "foo", "foo"], dtype=object)
b = np.array(["one", "one", "one", "two", "one", "one",
              "one", "two", "two", "two", "one"], dtype=object)
c = np.array(["dull", "dull", "shiny", "dull", "dull", "shiny",
              "shiny", "dull", "shiny", "shiny", "shiny"],
             dtype=object)

pd.crosstab = partial(pd.crosstab, margins=True)
print(pd.crosstab(a, [b, c], rownames=['a'], colnames=['b', 'c']))
```

Output:

```
b    one        two       All
c   dull shiny dull shiny    
a                            
bar    1     2    1     0   4
foo    2     2    1     2   7
All    3     4    2     2  11
```